# Call to a member function getTemplate() on boolean in

Tags: magento-1.9, error, template, controllers, action

After activate cache I got this error in controller:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getBlock() on string

Below is my controller action code:

```
public function loginAction()
{

if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    return;
}
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Login-Required', 'true');

$this->loadLayout();

$update = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate();
$update->addHandle('customer_account_login');
$this->loadLayoutUpdates();
$this->generateLayoutXml();
$this->generateLayoutBlocks();
$this->_isLayoutLoaded = true;

$blockList = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('customer_form_login');
$template = $blockList->getTemplate();
$blockChildBlock = $blockList->getChild();

$this->getLayout()->unsetBlock('customer_form_login');
$parentBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('vendorpos/customer_form_login','customer_form_login')->setTemplate($template);

if($blockChildBlock){
    foreach($blockChildBlock as $childBlock){
        $this->getChildBlockLogin($parentBlock,$childBlock);
    }
}

$this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
$this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
$this->renderLayout();
}
```

Comment: Try `$this->getBlock('customer_form_login');` instead of `$this->getLayout()->getBlock('customer_form_login');`, let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Comment following code from action

```
/*$update = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate();
$update->addHandle('customer_account_login');
$this->loadLayoutUpdates();
$this->generateLayoutXml();
$this->generateLayoutBlocks();
$this->_isLayoutLoaded = true;*/
```

and created layout file in `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\layoutname.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <layout_handler translate="label">
        <update handle="customer_account_login"/>
    </handler>
</layout>
```

This is not best solution for me because I did not want to use `.xml` file.